# Apache keeps reporting "python error: not main interpreter" on running django WSGI

Tags: python-3.x, apache, wsgi

Apache run django WSGI in docker container. Here are the versions:

**Apache version**: 2.4.6

**Python version**: 3.10.4

**mod_wsgi Version**: 4.9.0

**docker base image**: centos-7.9.2009

**httpd configuration:**

```
   ....
  LoadModule wsgi_module ${APP_ROOT_DIR}/common/conf/httpd/mod_wsgi-py310.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  WSGIPythonHome /opt/python-3.10.4

  Alias /na/static/ ${APP_ROOT_DIR}/publish/

  <Directory ${APP_ROOT_DIR}>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIDaemonProcess portal python-home=/opt/python-3.10.4 processes=1 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP} umask=027 socket-timeout=600
  WSGIScriptAlias /na ${APP_ROOT_DIR}/wsgi.py

  <Location /na>
    WSGIProcessGroup portal
  </Location>
......
```

**Repeat the errors in file 'httpd-error_log' below continuously:**

```
Extension modules: bson._cbson, pymongo._cmessage, cx_Oracle, pvectorc (total: 4)
Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_DeleteExceptMain: not main interpreter
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00007ff9d892d700 (most recent call first):
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 66 in _launch
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19 in __init__
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277 in _Popen
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121 in start
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 326 in _repopulate_pool_static
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 337 in _maintain_pool
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 513 in _handle_workers
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946 in run
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/opt/python-3.10.4/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from: https://githubhot.com/repo/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/750

The first suggestion change is instead of using:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ${url} user=${project-user} group=${project-group} python-path=${RootPath}/web/${url}/ python-home=${RootPath}/web/envs/${venv} display-name=${project} processes=3 threads=100 request-timeout=600
WSGIProcessGroup ${url}
WSGIScriptAlias / ${RootPath}/web/${url}/${app}/wsgi.py process-group=${url}
```

use:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ${url} user=${project-user} group=${project-group} python-path=${RootPath}/web/${url}/ python-home=${RootPath}/web/envs/${venv} display-name=${project} processes=3 threads=10 request-timeout=600
WSGIScriptAlias / ${RootPath}/web/${url}/${app}/wsgi.py process-group=${url} application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Also, outside of all VirtualHost configurations add:

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
```

This will disable Python being initialized in Apache child processes where it isn't being used.

In respect of mod_wsgi-express, you could learn something by looking at how it is configured as it has been tuned to work well for Python WSGI applications under Apache. Suggest if you haven't already, to watch:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6Q3l11fjU0